# Twitter Metadata is Kept When Appending Tweet Text to List

Tags: python, twitter, append, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to extract tweets from twitter using the twitter id (I have a dataset that contains twitter ids only). I was able to achieve that, however when using the tweepy client I can only extract 100 tweets at a time. I spread out the data into multiple google sheets and am planning to extract the tweets in batches. I am using a for loop to extract them and append them all to a list. The only problem is, when I print the output I get what I need (just the tweet text) but when I append to a list, it keeps all the metadata. Is there a way to append each clean tweet to a list?

Here's the code I use to extract them (in batches of 100)

```
new_list = []

import tweepy

id_list = df['id'].values.tolist()

client = tweepy.Client(bearer, key, key_secret, access_token, token_secret)

for tweet in id_list:
  some_tweet = client.get_tweet(id = tweet)
  tweet_text = some_tweet.data
  print(tweet_text)
  new_list.append(tweet_text)
```

When I use print(tweet_text) and comment out new_list.append(tweet_text) I get the output I want. Here's a sample of the tweets, they're clean:

```
i really doubt 2021 will be much different imo because corona will probably ruin it, so i’m not too excited but hopefully at some point the vaccine works and things can get a little better for everyone. but i still hope 2021 is good for you all regardless :) happy new year!!
None
so excited for The Vaccine that i got a tetanus vaccine today just to get in the spirit 
My mom has her appt for the Covid vaccine!! On the 14th. I’ve never seen someone so excited to get a shot before.
```

However, when I use new_list.append(tweet_text) print(tweet_text) and comment out print(tweet_text) I get a messy output that looks like this:

```
[None,
 <Tweet id=1344794858133860353 text='i really doubt 2021 will be much different imo because corona will probably ruin it, so i’m not too excited but hopefully at some point the vaccine works and things can get a little better for everyone. but i still hope 2021 is good for you all regardless :) happy new year!!'>,
 <Tweet id=1344789441764737024 text='so excited for The Vaccine that i got a tetanus vaccine today just to get in the spirit '>,
 <Tweet id=1344788417478062080 text='My mom has her appt for the Covid vaccine!! On the 14th. I’ve never seen someone so excited to get a shot before.'>]
```

Please let me know if there's a way I can get a clean output (or maybe even clean the messy output)

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Where is the  ' new_list' variable ?

is that full code or only required code for this error?

new_list = [] ?

may be if it is missed add that

Comment: Hi, I modified my post to show the 'new_list = []' in the code. I did include it in my code, just not in the post here so I'm not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).